# Select object and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<script>
    onKeyUp = function (src) {
        if (this.event.keyCode !== 13) {
            return;
        }

        var queryStringArray = [], queryString;
        var selectedElements = src.selectedOptions;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < selectedElements.length ; i++) {
            queryStringArray.push(selectedElements[i].getAttribute('value'));
        }
        queryString = queryStringArray.join('+');
        window.location.assign('http://example.co.il/tag/' + queryString);
    }
</script>
```

And works well with this:

```
<select data-placeholder="???" class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4" onkeyup="onKeyUp(this)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

I try to put him in my original file and then it does not work ..

**In my original file has jquery**

**The function did not run**

What to do?

Full Code: http://pastebin.com/PLHniVpr

Comment: Did you try to use document.ready() 
$(document).ready(function () {
 //your javascript
});

Comment: No. I'm not very good in this language..

Comment: If you have JQuery, I would not suggest to use onkeyup in your HTML, but add a listener to your Jquery script. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your original file has JQuery, why do you use onkeyup instead of adding a keyup listener for the select element to your Jquery code:

```
//assuming your select element has id="mySelect"  
$('#mySelect').keyup(function(event){
    var key = event.keyCode;
    if(key == 13) {
      var queryStringArray = [], queryString;
        var selectedElements = event.target.selectedOptions;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < selectedElements.length ; i++) {
            queryStringArray.push(selectedElements[i].getAttribute('value'));
        }
        queryString = queryStringArray.join('+');
        window.location.assign('http://example.co.il/tag/' + queryString);
    }
});
```

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/opgTbdH5eH7SWADvzwHB?p=preview)

Comment: How do I change it to send button (I think that's the problem)?

Comment: updated my answer with your code. does this work for you?

Comment: Errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined | Uncaught ReferenceError: SelectText is not defined

Comment: I have added a Plnkr to get you on track -- Note that when you use the button, you won't need the Jquery code anymore, but you can just add the functionality to the function that handles your button-click.

Comment: Fantastic! can you fix it for me?

Comment: I think you could manage that now with the use of the code + comments provided in the Plunker.

Comment: Can you please do me the code button is pressed it will take the information from the select?

Comment: Still not working. Something is blocking it. "Uncaught ReferenceError: SelectText is not defined"

Comment: I called my function selectText (camelCased). Note that the code is case sensitive. Please check if it matches the right case.

Comment: I can not find the problem

Answer (score 0):

put in windows load function it will work

```
<script>

winodow.onload =function(){
onKeyUp = function (src) {
    if (this.event.keyCode !== 13) {
        return;
    }

    var queryStringArray = [], queryString;
    var selectedElements = src.selectedOptions;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < selectedElements.length ; i++) {
        queryStringArray.push(selectedElements[i].getAttribute('value'));
    }
    queryString = queryStringArray.join('+');
    window.location.assign('http://example.co.il/tag/' + queryString);
}
}

////////or 
  $(document).ready(function(
 onKeyUp = function (src) {
    if (this.event.keyCode !== 13) {
        return;
    }

    var queryStringArray = [], queryString;
    var selectedElements = src.selectedOptions;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < selectedElements.length ; i++) {
        queryStringArray.push(selectedElements[i].getAttribute('value'));
    }
    queryString = queryStringArray.join('+');
    window.location.assign('http://example.co.il/tag/' + queryString);
}

));
```

Comment: what  error your getting in browser console ?can u check ?

Comment: It does not call that function. The script did not run at all.

Comment: SelectText() method ur not declared in file

Comment: What to do (I am beginner)?

Comment: what is ur requirement .tell me first ?

Comment: In the end I want it will take to address according to choice